# Remote desktop Gateway unavailable

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp, rdweb

I have set up a Remote desktop 2012 r2 session host set up,

When i access the RdWeb for my set up, login works fine but i get the error below when i launch the remote apps.

**Your computer can't connect to the remote computer because the Remote Desktop Gateway server is temporarily unavailable. Try reconnecting later or contact your network administrator for assistance.**

Points:

- I have set up the certificates, with the local certificate(RD server). - installed the same in trusted group in client server. - **nogoo**
- The RdWeb and remote apps work fine within the network, though i dont install the certificates
- the login is fine externally just the remote apps when accessed give the above error,
- i have tried manipulating the IIS, default settings with True/False - 32 bit apps - **nogo**
- I am accessing the Rdweb with IP address, as i am still testing the set up, and i am on local trail license.

Any assistance to fix this is really helpful

-pasha